# Undefined variable on switch via get method

Tags: php, switch-statement, content-management-system

I have a cms admin section with the option comments; when i press comments on the admin menu it should take me to comments.php which includes the code below; by default it should load all my comments on a grid, however when i press comments its not displaying anything the page is blank ? My code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['source'])){

    $source1=$_GET['source'];

if(!empty($source1)){ 

     switch($source1){

        case 'add_post':
            include"includes/add_posts.php";
        break;

        case 'edit_post':
            include"includes/edit_post.php";
            break;
     case 'view_all_comments':
         include "includes/view_all_comments.php";
            break;
        default:
            include "includes/view_all_comments.php";


    }
}


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when u load comments.php the url doesnt sent any parameter via get, on your code you are checking if the source is not empty which on your case its empty at first. Then preform switch statment, in your case it will not preform the switch as the source is empty and thats why you are not seeing anything. You can fix that by adding an else on your if and include view_all_comments.php or like the code below:

```
<?php


 $source1=isset($_GET['source']);
 switch($source1){

    case 'add_post':
        include"includes/add_posts.php";
    break;

    case 'edit_post':
        include"includes/edit_post.php";
    break;

    case 'view_all_comments':
     include "includes/view_all_comments.php";
    break;

    default:
        include "includes/view_all_comments.php";


}


?>
```